# SQLITE, Create a temp table then select from it

Tags: sqlite

just wondering how i can create a temp table and then select from it further down the script.

Example.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TABLE1 AS 
Select 
L.ID,
SUM(L.cost)/2 as Costs,
from Table1 L
JOIN Table2 C on L.ID = C.ID
Where C.name  = 'mike'
Group by L.ID



Select 
Count(L.ID)
from Table1 L
JOIN TEMP_TABLE1 TT1 on L.ID = TT1.ID;
Where L.ID not in (TT1) 
And Sum(L.Cost) > TT1.Costs
```

Ideally I want to have a temp table then use it later in the script to reference from.

Any help would be great!

Comment: More context please, and what you code you have this is/issnt working, and what you have tried so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Give more context....here is my code so far, and each part works when i run it one by one, however i want the first part to run, then the next in one go

<CODE> 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TABLE1 AS 
Select 
L.ID,
SUM(L.cost)/2 as Costs,
from Table1 L
JOIN Table2 C on L.ID = C.ID
Where C.name  = 'mike'
Group by L.ID

  
  
Select 
Count(L.ID)
from Table1 L
JOIN TEMP_TABLE1 TT1 on L.ID = TT1.ID;
Where L.ID not in (TT1) 
And Sum(L.Cost) > TT1.Costs
<CODE>

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to make the code stand out like my first post

Comment: Usually better to update the OP/Question, so next person doesnt dismiss as too vague or even downvote. Everyone can see the updated flag, so dont worry there

Comment: sorry, have updated my OP.

Comment: Okay... so thats not working??? Please lay out clearer what is and isnt working, any and all errors/logs that creates and what you tried to fix it so far

Answer (score 14):

You simply refer to the table as **`temp.<table>`** or **`<table>`** the latter only if it is a unique table name.

As per :-

> If a schema-name is specified, it must be either "main", "temp", or
>   the name of an attached database. In this case the new table is
>   created in the named database. If the "TEMP" or "TEMPORARY" keyword
>   occurs between the "CREATE" and "TABLE" then the new table is created
>   in the temp database. It is an error to specify both a schema-name and
>   the TEMP or TEMPORARY keyword, unless the schema-name is "temp". If no
>   schema name is specified and the TEMP keyword is not present then the
>   table is created in the main database.

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - CREATE TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)

The following example creates 3 tables :-

1. table1 with 3 columns as a permanent table.
2. table1 a temporary copy of the permanent table1.
3. temp_table another temporary copy of the permanent table1.

:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp.table1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table;
CREATE TABLE table1 (columnA INTEGER,columnB INTEGER, columnC INTEGER);
```

1. When creating the permanent table 1 it is loaded with 4 rows

:-

```
INSERT INTO table1 (columnA,columnB,columnC) VALUES 
 (1,5,20),
 (2,7,21),
 (3,8,80),
 (4,3,63);
CREATE TEMP TABLE table1 AS select * from table1;;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table AS SELECT * FROM table1;
```

1. both temp tables are then  used to in a union all to basically duplicate the rows, but with an indicator of the source table as a new column from_table

   1. Not that two forms of referring to the temp tables are used. **`temp.`** and just the table name.
   2. The latter only usable if the temporary table is a unique table name.

:-

```
SELECT 'temp_table' AS from_table,* FROM temp_table
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'temp.table1' as from_table,* FROM temp.table1;
```

The result being :-

[image]

---

### Re addition of example :-

> ```
> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_TABLE1 AS 
> Select 
> L.ID,
> SUM(L.cost)/2 as Costs,
> from Table1 L
> JOIN Table2 C on L.ID = C.ID
> Where C.name  = 'mike'
> Group by L.ID
>
>
>
> Select 
> Count(L.ID)
> from Table1 L
> JOIN TEMP_TABLE1 TT1 on L.ID = TT1.ID;
> Where L.ID not in (TT1) 
> And Sum(L.Cost) > TT1.Costs
> ```

There are a few issues with this example bar the misuse of the aggregate (commented out) the following works.

- **Note** for my convenience I've added an **`_`** to the table names.

:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table_1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table_2;
DROP TABLE If EXISTS temp.temp_table1;
CREATE TABLE Table_1 (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, cost REAL);
CREATE TABLE Table_2 (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
INSERT INTO Table_1 (cost) VALUES (100.45),(56.78),(99.99);
INSERT INTO Table_2 (name) VALUES ('mike'),('mike'),('fred');

CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_table1 AS
SELECT L.ID, 
    sum(L.cost)/2 as Costs
FROM Table_1 L
    JOIN Table_2 C ON L.ID = C.ID
WHERE C.name = 'mike'
GROUP BY L.ID;

SELECT 
    count(L.ID)
FROM Table_1 L
   JOIN temp_table1 TT1 ON  L.ID = TT1.[L.ID]
WHERE 
    L.ID NOT IN (TT1.[L.ID])
    -- AND Sum(L.cost) > TT1.costs --<<<< misuse of aggregate
```

The issues are based upon the column name being **`L.ID`** so this has to be enclosed (rules here [SQL As Understood By SQLite - SQLite Keywords](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) apply) **`[`** and **`]`** have been used above.

- of course you could circumvent the need for enclosure by naming the column using **`AS`** e..g `SELECT 
  L.ID AS lid, --<<<< AS lid ADDED
  SUM(L.cost)/2 as Costs, ,.......`

Adding the following may be suitable for getting around the misuse of aggregate :-

```
GROUP BY L.ID
HAVING sum(L.cost) > TT1.costs
```

---

Adding the following to the end of the script :-

```
 SELECT 
    count(L.ID), *
FROM Table_1 L
   JOIN temp_table1 TT1 ON  L.ID = TT1.[L.ID];
```

results in :-

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If this is only to be used by one SELECT statement then you can use the [WITH](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) clause:

```
WITH TmpTable(id,cost) AS 
(
    ...SELECT statement that returns the two columns (id and cost)...
)
SELECT id, cost FROM TmpTable WHERE ...;
```