# Temp tables causing error while writing this code

Tags: sql, sqlite

Trying to run this code:

```
create temporary table Sandals
(select * from Shoes where Type='Sandals')
```

results in an error:

> Uncaught Error: near "select": syntax error

Comment: This is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093776/sqlite-create-a-temp-table-then-select-from-it

Comment: You forgot the AS keyword: `create temporary table sandals AS select...` (and there is no need to put the query between parentheses)